# Windows 7 PID consumes 50% CPU almost everyday for hours

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, pid

I'm trying to determine why these services consume 50% of my CPU for hours at a time each day.  I cannot restart the services without error and killing the PID just restarts it in a few minutes and it's back to chewing through CPU.

Using process explorer these are the DLL's that run under the PID in question.

Windows 7
I take MS updates about once a month.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: usually the recommended approach is to systematically disable the services within that instance, until the processing goes away, at which point you have identified the culprit.

Comment: @FrankThomas - These seems like fundamental windows services though?  I can try but I'm curious if it will cause significant issues with Win7 doing so?

Comment: most if not all of them can be disabled for at least a period of time. but you don't want to stop them all. that tells us nothing. I'm guessing its bits or Windows Update, but who knows. what you are seeing isn't normal, so theres no universal fix for what you are describing. if it is wuauserv, then stop the service, delete your c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\ directory, and start the service back up. If its another service, then you will have to troubleshoot it once identified.

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a whirl tonight when I get home and report back the results.

Comment: My bet is Windows update running in the background.

Comment: Threads view/tab doesn't gives any hints?

Comment: have you tried to install the update? does it solve the issue?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes I installed the update and it did not fix the issue.  The CPU usage is coming from Windows Update however.  Im still trying to determine a fix.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the slow WU: http://pastebin.com/LCP8HgPy (the Win8.1 SDK also works on Win7)

Comment: have you captured the xperf trace to see what WU is still doing?

Comment: I have not had a chance to do that yet.  I will post an update when I do.

Comment: Fixed by installing Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Windows Update service. Microsoft fixed this in a new WindowsUpdate Client Update.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

Try this new Update and look if it reduces the CPU usage.